# How did Madara Uchiha give his Rinnegan to Nagato?

Tags: naruto

We have seen that Madara had awakened his left eye to a Rinnegan. But Nagato's both eyes have Rinnegan when they are transplanted.

How did Madara Uchiha give his Rinnegan to Nagato?

Answer (score 1):

Madara had activated Izanagi in his right eye. Using this forbidden jutsu, he came back to life after Hashirama killed him.

Because he used Izanagi, the light/sight of the right eye was removed. Because that's the price you have to pay when you use Izanagi or Izanami.

Madara had bit off a piece of Hashirama's flesh during the battle. After he came back alive, he went into hiding, planting a clone in his tomb. Then he surgically attached the flesh onto his body and waited.

Near the end of his natural life, he awoke the Rinnegan in both eyes. This awakening restored the sight in his right eye, a unique property of the Rinnegan.

Since he was nearing death and was unable to complete his plans, he transplanted his eyes to a Senju descendant, Nagato. The technique he used is not mentioned anywhere, but it would be a piece of cake for him, because of his intelligence and the help from Zetsu.

Comment: To add to this, considering that Nagato himself didn't know about the transplantation, Madara must have used genjutsu on him on the night Nagato's parents were murdered. In fact, it might be Madara himself that killed Nagato's parents and make it as if it was Konoha ninjas that did it using genjutsu.

Comment: Possible. Only Kishi sensei knows..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, Madara awakened Rinnegan in both his eyes. He used Hashirama's cells to achieve the result, which affected both his eyes. The reason it seemed only his one eye had Rinnegan was because of his hairstyle which covered his other eye.

Comment: But Madara loses his right eye as he used the Izanagi to revive himself.

Comment: Madara used Izanagi when he had EMS. He awakened Rinnegan later on in his life. **I'm assuming** that when he awakened Rinnegan, his other eye also got back its vision. @BlackPegasus

Answer (score 0):

Eye transplants before his death. He choose an Uzumaki because he believed that they were able to wield it as well as an Uchiha.

Answer (score 0):

Madara gave both his rinnegans to Nagato and when he was revived with Edo Tensei, the jutsu gave him some fake eyes to make him appear as he was before death (or when the sample for the jutsu was collected). So when he was actually revived and came back to life, He was revived the way he died( without his own eyes). Then he takes back only one of his rinnegans because the other one is being used by Tobi. He steals the eye back from Tobi later on to complete his state.